# Using Java FX to create a seating chart for a Theatre split up into 3 sections. 3X20 seats total

Tags: java, javafx

Creating a theatre with 3 sections, I need to create a JAva fx graphic to show the seats available and a seating chart of the entire 3x20 array.

My professor has shown a tutorial on how to do it and given the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Button;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    public class yrue extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn=new Button("OK");
    Scene sc= new Scene(btn,200,200);
    primaryStage.setScene(sc);
    primaryStage.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Application.launch(args);
   }
   }
```

However,
all i get are errors in the importing,Application Button and Scene objects. Just says Error:

```
Unable to initialize main class;
Caused by: java.langNoClassDefFoundError:Stage
```

To set up Java FX, I added the userLibrary with JavaFX files imported just like her tuturial said. I am on a mac.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Either use [a version of the JDK that contains JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67861893/dont-know-how-to-install-javafx-for-my-java-version/67861944#67861944), or follow the getting started instructions at openjfx.io, or (if using idea IDE), use its new JavaFX project wizard. Use recent software versions, as M1 macs (if you have one) aren’t supported on earlier versions.

Comment: Your question title is irrelevant to your actual questions.  The nature and detail of your assignment is not relevant to your issue, which is how to setup a working JavaFX development environment.